# How to unify the logic of inside and outside of loop so no repetition?

Tags: c#, foreach

see....

I have a logic

which is like

```
objRoles.Delete

objRoles.add()
```

etc

but this `objRoles` is supposed to checked at 2 places.

For example;

Before going to `objRoles` I have to check if some other object is full filling the criteria.

e.g.

```
var userCollection= db.UsersCollection.Where(r=> r.Active== true).ToList();

if(userCollection.Count() > 0) 
{   
        //will keep on looping for all users and do the steps that i mentioned
        objRoles.where(u=> u.UserID == userCollection.UserId);
        objRoles.Delete

        objRoles.add()
         
        //and long list of steps on objRoles.
}
```

but it's not necessary that `userCollection` would be filled but still the same steps needs to be done for `objRoles` but not looping.

but I don't want to repeart the logic of delete, add and others.

how to unify them ? So I don't have to repeat logic.

Comment: Its unclear on what you are trying to achieve or what the problem is, can you clarify a little more?

Comment: What is `objRoles`? Is it a list?

Comment: Hi, it's done. I just wrote a separate function.